# What would be the best method of creating a block which outputs a Redstone Signal

Tags: minecraft-forge

I'm wondering what would be the best way to allow a block to send out a specific amount of Redstone output conditionally. While looking through other blocks that gave a Redstone output, I noticed that they were mostly using the `getWeakPower()` method. However, I noticed that this was a Deprecated method and my IDE formats the method with a strikethrough. Additionally, I also found another method named `getStrongPower()` (also Deprecated). Which one of these two method would be best to override or would there be a better way to set the Redstone output of a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although these blocks have the `@Deprecated` annotation to them, the JavaDoc comment states that "Implementing/overriding is fine". These `getWeakPower()` and `getStrongPower()` methods are only flagged as being deprecated in the `net.minecraft.block.Block` class because they are not meant to be accessed from the Block class, instead they are supposed to be accessed from the `net.minecraft.block.BlockState` class as that will contain the most up to date state of a given block instance.

It seems that most blocks which use Redstone functionality override the `getWeakPower()` method to control the Redstone output of the block by returning a specific value from 0 to 15 from the method. It’s also possible to separately control the output of each side (only output on one side or different outputs on each side), by using the `Direction` parameter passed into the method to determine the returned value.

Note: You must override the canProvidePower() method to return true. Otherwise, neighboring blocks will not check the block for a Redstone output and the desired functionality won’t work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work and the Redstone Dust doesn't even connect with the block

Comment: @user96384 you must override the canProvidePower() method and return true to make sure that neighboring blocks check for a redstone output. I forgot to write this in the answer and I'll make an edit promptly.